# How to speed up this calculation regarding the normal distribution?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, distributions

This calculation takes a very long time!

1. Why?
2. How can I improve it?

Thanks!

```
n[μ_] := Integrate[1/(0.3 Sqrt[2 π]) E^(-(1/2) ((x - μ)/0.3)^2), {x, -∞, 501.13}]

Solve[n[μ] == 0.05]
```

Comment: try  replacing  `.3` and `501.13` with `Rationalize[0.3]` and `Rationalize[ 501.13]`

Comment: Works quite fast:`Solve[Integrate[5/3 E^(-(50/9) (x - μ)^2) Sqrt[2/π], {x, -∞, 50113/100}] == 5/100, μ][[1]] // AbsoluteTiming (* {2.81637, {μ -> 1/100 (50113 + 30 Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[1/10])}*)`

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe...

Comment: @kglr Interesting! Why does Rationalize work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dist = NormalDistribution[μ, 3/10];
```

The integral is

```
n[μ_] = Integrate[PDF[dist, x], {x, -∞, 50113/100}]

(* 1/2 Erfc[(-50113 + 100 μ)/(30 Sqrt[2])] *)
```

Alternatively, it is just the CDF

```
n2[μ_] = CDF[dist, 50113/100]

(* 1/2 Erfc[5/3 Sqrt[2] (-(50113/100) + μ)] *)
```

Verifying that they are equivalent expressions,

```
n[μ] == n2[μ] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The exact solution is

```
sol = Solve[n[μ] == 1/20, μ][[1]] // Quiet

(* {μ -> 1/100 (50113 + 30 Sqrt[2] InverseErfc[1/10])} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
n[μ] /. sol

(* 1/20 *)
```

The numeric value is

```
sol // N

(* {μ -> 501.623} *)
```

Comment: Instead of using `Solve[]` here, it is better to use the intended functions `Quantile[]` or `InverseCDF[]`.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. - seems like `Solve` or `Reduce` would still be needed, e.g., `Solve[Quantile[dist, 1/20] == 50113/100, μ][[1]]` or `Solve[InverseCDF[dist, 1/20] == 50113/100, μ][[1]]`

Answer (score 4):

We have the identity

```
CDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x] == CDF[NormalDistribution[], (x - μ)/σ] // Simplify
   True
```

which means

```
With[{σ = 3/10, p = 1/20, x = 50113/100},
         x - σ Quantile[NormalDistribution[], p]] // N
```

is the solution to the problem posed in the OP.

Comment: (I only have a smartphone and *gedanken Mathematica* right now, so please edit my answer if the formatting looks off.)

Comment: "I only have a smartphone and *gedanken Mathematica* right now"...Now that's what I call confidence and a good memory.  (And no surprise, it checks out.)

Comment: It ain't a great situation, but I'm making the most of what I have. :)