# How to solve when using a Cumulative Binomial Distribution function?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

This is probably very simple, but I could not find the answer. How to solve? I tried `Reduce` as well to no avail.

```
dist[j_] := CDF[BinomialDistribution[1001, 1/2], j]
Solve[dist[j] <= 1/2]
```

Comment: `InverseCDF[BinomialDistribution[1001, 1/2], 1/2]`. Use the function intended for the purpose. (The situation is similar to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183509).)

Comment: Or `Median[BinomialDistribution[1001, 1/2]]`